# Dot product between NumPy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas Series object called X, which has dimension (100,). Each element of X is mapped to a NumPy ndarray of floating point numbers, with shape (10, 10). I also have another Pandas Series object called Y, which also has dimension (100,). Each element of Y is mapped to a Pandas DataFrame; each DataFrame contains only floating point numbers, and is of size (10, 10). Both X and Y have the same indices - all indices are of type DatetimeIndex.

I want to perform the operation X•Y•X, where "•" is the dot product. I want a solution that works, and is robust to the presence of `NaN`s. How can I do this? The attempts below have all failed, and I'm not sure why:

```py
date_index = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', periods=100, freq='D')
labels = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY')
X = pd.Series([np.random.rand(25, 25) for _ in range(100)], index=date_index)
Y = pd.Series([pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(25, 25), index=labels[:25], columns=labels[:25]) for _ in range(100)], index=date_index)



# Attempt 1:
X.dot(Y).dot(X) ## ValueError: matrices are not aligned



# Attempt 2:
dot_products = lambda x, y: np.dot(np.dot(x, y), x)
X.apply(lambda x: dot_products(x, Y.loc[x])) # ValueError - can't index with multidimensional key
```

Comment: Dot product doesn't function that way. The first dot product will have dimension 1, which cannot dot product with dimension (10, 10). Do you want it to be a scalar multiplication at that point? Or do you want something like the sum of `x_ij * y_ij * x_ij`?

Comment: I want a matrix multiplication; for example, if you take the 0th element of both X and Y and perform the operation I described using X.dot(Y).dot(X), you get an answer.

Comment: Perhaps not the most efficient, but you could loop through each date: `P = pd.Series();
for i in X.index: P[i] = X.loc[i].dot(Y.loc[i])`

Comment: Just to be sure, are you sure you want matrix multiplication? Because that's `np.matmul`

Comment: Yes @MichaelCao

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best way is to broadcast X and Y to shape (100, 10, 10):

```
xmat = np.array([x for x in X])
ymat = np.array([y for y in Y])

xyx = xmat @ ymat @ xmat
```

The issue at play is that numpy.dot sees X and Y as 1-D vectors, so it does an inner dot product. I'm not sure whether it's doing an element-wise multiplication or matrix multiplication, but it sums along the date dimension, giving a (10, 10) (or (25,25) in your code example) result. Then you try to dot product a (100,) with a (10, 10) which it doesn't know how to resolve. Exposing the full dimensionality of X and Y addresses this.